# How to replace a div content opened in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

In iframe I have opened another website and want to change the div content within the iframe.

I have tried this but not working

```
$('#iframe #divId').html('New text');
```

Comment: please show your html content

Comment: If the iframe has not the same domain as the window, you can't

Answer (score 0):

If the website inside the iframe is from another origin (or simplified - from another domain), then JavaScript's security policy doesn't allow such operations.

But if the website is from the same origin, then using jQuery call

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("#divId").html("New text");
```

but be sure to call it when the framed document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

**wrap that iframe within a div and try this**

```
$('#iframe').parent("div").html('New text');
```